# FInding File Information Using Search String:

Tags: file, grep, find

Is there a **single Command in Unix** to get the following Information when searching (case insensitive)  files containing one or more strings in a Unix Directory (including sub directories within it) :

1) Complete filename ( path and filename)
    2) Owner of the file
    3) Size of the file
    4) Last Modified date
    5) The matching Line in the File containing the strings.

I used this Command to search for string 'TEST' and 'BEST':

```
find  /shrproj/files    -type f -name '*.sas'    | xargs egrep -Ri   'TEST|BEST'
```

**Result :**

> /shrproj/files/sas_apps/IVR_Campaign_File_Load.sas:  TESTING sample
>
> /shrproj/files/aea_aat/IVR_Campaign1_File_Load.sas: BEST Innings

As seen in above Result I only  get the Information 1)  and 5) from
the above command.**How do i get information 2) ,3) and 4) for  these files also?** Can some modification be made to above command to get this information too?

Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /shrproj/files -type f -name '*.sas' -exec egrep -i 'TEST|BEST' {} \; -ls
```

`grep` will show the matching lines, and then the `-ls` option of `find` will show the file's attributes. If `grep` doesn't find any matching lines, it returns a non-zero exit status, and `find` treats that as `false`, so it doesn't execute remaining options.

Comment: I appreciate your Quick Resonse to my Question.Your Command was VERY HELPFUL and was EXACTLY what i needed.